# How to generate the right connection string for MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, connection-string

I have `ASP.Net MVC` site & using `EF Code First`

As Database, I am using `MySql`.  But not getting the right connection string. If it was MSSQL I could have easily generate using Visual Studio itself.

Is there a quick way to auto generate the right connection string when using MySql.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be useful

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=mydbname;uid=my_user_id;password=my_password"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

tipically  the my_user_id = root

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: Can you please look into this related question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572912/the-type-initializer-for-system-data-entity-migrations-dbmigrationsconfiguratio

Answer (score 0):

While adding the edmx file (under data tab) you have select generate from existing db. And select mysql db for more details follow the complete guide 
[here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264)